# Can an ultrapower be undone by class forcing?

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, forcing

Suppose I have a transitive model $M$ of ZFC, and - in $M$ - $U$ is a measure on $\kappa$. Then the transitive collapse of the ultrapower of $M$ along $U$ is an inner model, $N\subset M$.

My question is:

> Can we ever have $M$ be a class-generic extension of $N$?

*Context*: The set-forcing version of this question [was answered by Douglas Ulrich](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/227049/can-an-ultrapower-be-undone-by-forcing/227052#227052), using a result of Hamkins-Kirmayer-Perlmutter; and Joel David Hamkins pointed out that the same result holds for many "nice" class forcings. However, the general class-forcing version remains open, and general class forcing is potentially *so* nasty that I thought this warranted its own question.

Comment: Well, undoing an ultrapower means resurrecting the measurability of a smaller cardinal. If that's even possible, I'd imagine some very very large cardinals are involved; and the measure being something like some type of a huge measure or so.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Kunen showed long ago that a non-measurable cardinal can become measurable in a forcing extension, and the consistency strength is just a measurable cardinal. You start with $\kappa$ measurable, and then kill it in a way that it can be resurrected.

Comment: @Joel: Yes, by adding Cohen sets below the measurable, I know (and this way it ends up immune to Cohen sets). But never the less, this is a *very* different situation from taking an inner model which is an ultrapower by a measure.

Comment: I was merely responding to your statement, "...resurrecting the measurability of a smaller cardinal. If that's even possible...".  It is possible, by Kunen's theorem. I agree that this does not shed light on Noah's question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is negative, if one considers parameter-free definable ZFC-preserving class forcing satisfying the forcing theorem, which means that the forcing
relation is definable and true statements in the extension are
forced.

**Theorem.** Suppose that $\newcommand\P{\mathbb{P}}\P$ is a
ZFC-preserving definable class forcing notion in $M$ that satisfies the forcing
theorem for forcing over $M$. Then in the corresponding forcing
extension $V$ of $M$ by $\P$, there is no elementary embedding
$j:V\to M$ that is definable in $V$ from parameters.

**Proof.** Suppose not. Fix such a forcing notion $\P$ in $M$,
defined by $\varphi(\cdot)$, and suppose that $j(x)=y$ is forced to
be defined in $V$ by $\psi(x,y,\dot u)$.

Let $\kappa$ be least such that there is a condition forcing that
in the forcing extension of $M$, there is a parameter $u$ for which
the formula $\psi(x,y,u)$ defines an elementary embedding $j:V\to
M$. This is expressible in the first-order language of set theory. Consequently, we have given a parameter-free definition of $\kappa$ in $M$. This contradicts the fact that $j:V\to M$ is an
elementary embedding with critical point $\kappa$, since in this
case $\kappa$ will not be in the range of $j$, but every definable
element of $M$ will be in the range of $j$. Contradiction. **QED**

A similar argument works in the case that $\P$ is definable in $M$
from parameters below $\kappa$.

In the general case, let me now undertake a more general argument,
in the case that $\P$ is definable by a formula $\psi(\cdot,z)$
using a parameter $z$, but I shall use an extra assumption. Specifically, I want it to be first-order expressible in a parameter $z'$, whether the class forcing notion defined by $\psi(\cdot,z')$ satisfies the forcing theorem and what is the forcing relation.

**Theorem.** Suppose that $\P$ is a ZFC-preserving class forcing notion definable
from parameters in $M$ and satisfying the forcing theorem, such
that the definition $\psi(\cdot,z)$ of $\P$ has the property that
the property of whether $\psi(\cdot,z)$ defines such a class
forcing notion with the forcing theorem is itself expressible in
set theory, and the forcing relation is also definable from that parameter uniformly. Then in the forcing extension $V$ of $M$ by $\P$, there
is no elementary embedding $j:V\to M$ that is definable in $V$ from
parameters.

**Proof.** Let $\kappa$ be least among all parameters $z$ such that
it is the critical point of such an embedding. Now we don't need
the parameter $z$ to define $\kappa$ in $M$, and get the
contradiction as before. **QED**

I'm not sure in general how to express that a definable class has
the forcing theorem, uniformly in the parameter. Even in the case
of pre-tame forcing, this seems to involve quantifying over
arbitrary classes and has complexity $\Pi^1_1$ over $M$.