# Examples of the use of forcing to build up models of stronger theories?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, forcing

I'm very new to the subject of forcing. I always got the impression that with forcing we begin with say a model $M$ of a theory $\sf T+I$ and produce another model $M[G]$ that is also a model of $\sf T$ but in which $\sf I$ can fail! So, there is no difference in consistency strength between the theory we began with and the one we've ended in.

However, I've recently new of a counter example where the end looks much stronger than the beginning.

Per Mathias, lets work within a universe $V$ in which all of $\sf ZF$ is true, fix a limit ordinal $\lambda > \omega$, let $M$ be the union of all transitive sets whose intersection with $\lambda$ is strictly bounded below $\lambda$. Now $M$, a model of $\sf Z$, satisfy existence of transitive closures for all sets, and existence of $V_\alpha$ for every ordinal $\alpha$, but there exists sets in $M$ for which no rank can be assigned to!

If we force over $M$ using the Shoenfield-Kunen definitions of forcing and the partial order with exactly one element, call it $1$, then we get back the original $\sf ZF$ universe V in which we are working!

So $M$ a model of $\sf Z$ that violates $\sf ZF$, carried the seeds of $\sf ZF$ within it, that applying forcing on it can yield the full $\sf ZF$ again!

> What are other examples of that phenomena? That is, using forcing to build up models of STRONGER theories?

Comment: *Most* examples of forcing can be construed to be of this type: we can view any "negative" example $$M\models T+X,\quad M[G]\models T+\neg X$$ as a "positive" example $$M\models T, M\not\models Y,\quad M[G]\models T+Y$$ (with $Y=\neg X$). I think it will take some care to isolate the phenomenon you're interested in in a meaningful way. That said, you may be interested in results about when large cardinal instances can(not) be forced to appear. For example, inaccessibility is downwards-absolute so can't be added by forcing, but measurability [can be](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/110871/).